# Where can I find complete documentation on NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, documentation, nsdictionary

The documentation for `NSDictionary` seems incomplete. Where can I find a complete version?

For instance, where do I find the documentation which *fully* explains `keysSortedByValueWithOptions:usingComparator:`. The docs with iOS 4.3 fail to define what "options" there are.

Comment: By the way, you should [report this as a doc bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Did. I sometimes despair of that sort of thing, they really don't get back to people... But then I got pissed about something else, and wrote to Tim Cook, and a VP called me to assure me that they got the message, and they'll do what they can. I then got the chance to talk to him about the policy of not getting back to people. He said it was very difficult, because they don't want to give the impression that they aren't listening, but they also don't want to give the impression they implement feedback directly, because people start to decide they should get compensation for suggestions.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty good! Understandable position on their part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the docs; you can often find other tidbits of information doing a web search (http://cocoadev.com is a good resource, as is SO, of course), but there's no "more complete" version of the Apple documentation.

For this particular case, a [search for "sort options"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/index.php?Search=sort+options) turns up the [Foundation Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/), which contains an [`enum` of Sort Options](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW196).

Interestingly, I just noticed that [`-[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsWithOptions%3ausingBlock%3a) *does* explain the available options, so this is definitely an oversight. You should [send in a doc bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the Apple docs are what the Apple docs are -- some of the worst in the industry.  Most notably they seem to have been built without knowledge of the concept of HTML links, so stuff that should be directly linked isn't.  You often end up having to do a web search for some details, and after a while you learn that a lot of secrets are hidden in the [Foundation Data Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) and other such documents that you'd never find on a "top down" search of the Apple pubs "tree".

(Eg, look at the [Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) pubs, and the pubs for [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/).  In both cases, when you look at the definition for a class, you can easily identify all of the implemented fields/methods, including those of superclasses.  Only in the Apple docs do you have to manually dig through the superclass and protocol definitions to find everything.)